# Sorting a list with compare function

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a `list<CMail>` ( where CMail is some object, not important for purpose of this question ). Now, I'd like to sort it.
I am aware that list has a sort() function, which either uses standard operator< etc., or given compare function. And I do have such a function.

my function

```
bool comp( const CMail & x ) const;
```

returns, if we do consider a.comp(b); , true if a < b, and false otherwise.
This function is also part of CMail class and therefore CMail namespace.

Now, I'd like to use this sorting function, and I'm using

```
temp.sort( CMail::comp );
```

where temp is a

```
list<CMail> temp;
```

But, compiler doesnt let me, saying

> error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘bool CMail::comp(const CMail&) const’

does anyone see where the problem could be? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison has to be a binary functor that can compare all elements of the list. The member function `CMail::comp` does not satisfy that. Try a non-member. This can be implemented in terms of your member `CMail::comp`:

```
bool comp(const CMail& lhs, const CMail& rhs )
{
  return lhs.comp(rhs);
}
```

and then

```
temp.sort(comp);
```

Alternatively, use a lambda:

```
temp.sort([](const CMail& lhs, const CMail& rhs ){return lhs.comp(rhs);});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I now understand what the problem was. I made another function, expecting 2 arguments of CMail type, however, compiler now says:
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘bool (CMailBox::*)(const CMail&, const CMail&)const
Can I maybe change the type with some cast or something?

Comment: @MichalKučera your function should be a non-member. Otherwise you have to use `std:bind`.

Comment: all working properly now :). Thank your very much sir

Answer (score 0):

Change your comp function to static.  You are trying to access it with no object instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

The non-member function used as a comparison has to take two arguments and return bool

```
bool comp( const CMail & x1, const CMail& x2) {
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::list<CMail> l;
    l.assign( 4, CMail());
    l.sort( &comp);
}
```

In C++11 you can use lambda function. Here is example which calls a member function `CMail::comp`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::list<CMail> l;
    l.assign( 4, CMail());
    l.sort( [](const CMail& x1, const CMail& x2) { return x1.comp( x2);});
                                                           ^^^^ //member function
}
```